# PHP multiple loops through multidimensional arrays with stdObjects

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to object oriented PHP and multidimensional arrays, and I am needing some help. I want to print out the name of each course, and the students assigned to each course. Right now my code is printing out the name of each course, but it is not printing out student names under the course. What am I doing wrong? It appears everything below line 4 is not working. Why not?

Please note: $roster is the array that has all this stored.

**My code:**

```
    echo "<pre>Class List";
    foreach ($roster as $value) {
      echo $value->class->name;
      echo "<br>";

      foreach ($value->students->nextPageToken->students as $child) {
        echo $child->profile->name->fullName;
        echo "<br>";
      }

    }
```

**What the array looks like: (just a sample)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [class] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Course One

                )

            [students] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nextPageToken] => 
                    [students] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [courseId] => 2198507574
                                    [userId] => 1111582822133286313
                                    [profile] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [emailAddress] => johnsmith@schools.org
                                            [id] => 111158282162133286313
                                            [verifiedTeacher] => 
                                            [name] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [familyName] => SMITH
                                                    [fullName] => JOHN SMITH
                                                    [givenName] => JOHN
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [courseId] => 2198507574
                                    [userId] => 1095912136541834087
                                    [profile] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [emailAddress] => janedoe@schools.org
                                            [id] => 1095912136375414087
                                            [verifiedTeacher] => 
                                            [name] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [familyName] => JANE
                                                    [fullName] => JANE DOE
                                                    [givenName] => DOE
                                                )

                                        )

                                )
```

Comment: `students` is not inside `nextPageToken`. It should just be `$value->students->students`

Comment: If it were inside, you would see another `stdClass Object` header.

Comment: What exactly is a nextPageToken then? This makes sense!

Comment: It's an empty string. Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, it's clearer.